# Ошибка 502 в системе opencart 3

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Стоит Opencart 3.0.3 Сегодня возникла проблема.
На вкладке Панели состояния, когда нажимаю на значок синий с шестеренкой, чтобы очистить кеш, вместо того самого попапа выдает в окошке такую ошибку:

> Bad Gateway

В чем причина может быть?

Comment: Переносили папку со статикой?

Comment: Кирилл, к своему стыду не понимаю, имеете ввиду папку admin?

Comment: В админке появлялось сообщение с предложением перенести storage directory?

Comment: Да, когда устанавливал систему, по предложению перенес ее

Comment: После переноса норм работало и кеши чистились?

Comment: Да, все было нормально до сегодняшнего дня.

Comment: удалите руками всё из storage/cache (там где её переместили на хосте). Если не поможет или поможет временно - дёргайте хостера. Похоже на траблу с их стороны, если вы ничего не правили непосредственно перед возникновение проблемы и точно уверены что ваши действия не могли спровоцировать сие.

Comment: ок, сейчас попробую

Comment: Кирилл, удалял не помогло.
Знаете, что помогло - восстановил из папки catalog/controller/common файлы footer.php и header.php, так как заметил что сегодня только к ним прикасался, ну понятно за исключением операций в админке. Вот такое интересное явление. Хотя подумать, как эти файлы относятся с работе админ панели

Comment: Кирилл, не знаете случайно, почему не могу удалить статью.
Сообщение гласит: Эту страницу нельзя удалить, так как она назначена Условиями соглашения по умолчанию!

Comment: Потому, что в настройках она обозначена для tetms&conditions

Comment: Кирилл, и можете также подсказать, если не трудно (не хочу наглеть, но встретил вас, и вижу что вы компетентны).
Что хотел узнать - возможно ли создать страницу со своей версткой, из того блока где контакты, возврат и тд., чтобы на этой странице была уникальная верстка вобщем, и только на ней

Comment: Да. Контроллер information/contact отвечает за рендеринг страницы Контакты. В конце метода index есть строчка $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('information/contact', $data)); В ней 'information/contact' это роут к файлу шаблона. дальше, думаю, разберётесь ;)

Comment: Ого! Спасибо огромное )

Comment: эх, а он заменяет) информация очень полезна на будущее, этого не отнять, Кирилл, спасибо
но мне нужно было бы именно добавить страницу, а не заменять.

Comment: Всё идентично. В папке контроллера создаёте свой контроллер, свою вьюху. Всё по примеру существующих файлов. Роут у новой страницы будет имя_папки/имя_контроллера.